# Does Razor support elseif?

Tags: razor, intellisense

Intellisense makes it look like probably not.

Comment: What's wrong with plain `else if`?

Comment: Razor's just a syntax - tokens, really. The language you use will be pure C# or VB

Comment: Why is @justSteve not allowed to say thanks (Revisions 1 and 3)?

Comment: Remember, don't use the @ sign. "@else if" does not work since you're already in "code-mode"

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Since you didn't specify a language I'll give you both. :)

#### CSharp

```cs
@if (true) {
    AlwaysDoStuff();
} else if (false) { 
    NeverDoThis();
}
```

#### Visual Basic

```vb
@If True Then
    AlwaysDoStuff()
ElseIf False Then
    NeverDoThis()
End If
```

Comment: @justSteve: Nope.  Both Razor and ASPX use the same syntax as the underlying language.